# Static and Global?

Tags: php, forms, global

I've looked through the PHP documentation and it seems like this is possible, but it's still dropping my variable values with global.  Is there something I'm missing?

I set $var to a value.  Then declare it global $var.  Then the value shouldn't change and I will be able to use it globally right?  Forgive my ignorance, I'm new to this.

Comment: Please provide a code sample. It's not really clear what you want.

Comment: I'm pulling the ID field from a MySQL database and setting it to $uid.  I need to be able to reference that value through a ton of nested loops and if else statements and in the process the value is getting dropped somewhere.

Comment: I think you need to use it static in place of global.... value of static will not change once defined.....whereas global can be used in any scope.......

Comment: Vikas, I need it to be static as well as global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `global` keyword does not make a variable global, it makes the variable accessible in the context of a function.

If you want to make a variable global you can use the `$GLOBALS` array

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

> The $GLOBALS array is an associative array with the name of the global variable being the key and the contents of that variable being the value of the array element. Notice how $GLOBALS exists in any scope, this is because $GLOBALS is a superglobal.

```
$GLOBALS['myvar'] = 'test'; // $GLOBALS['myvar'] can now be accessed in any scope
```

Comment: and now you can access the var by just $GLOBALS['myvar'] or global $myvar; print $myvar;

Comment: Access it simply with `$GLOBALS['myvar']` for example: `print $GLOBALS['myvar'];`

Comment: I declared it $GLOBALS['uid'] = $uid; and then reference it later by echo $GLOBALS['uid']; and it outputs nothing.  I echo $uid before registering it as global and it outputs the ID.  I don't get it.

Comment: Does it need to exist across multiple pages? if so $_SESSION is what you need. If not, there must be some code that is unsetting/nulling it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using a superglobal variable instead. You can do this using a $GLOBALS variable.

```
$GLOBALS['newvar'] = 'foo';
```

If you're trying to access the variable between, say, two different documents you can use sessions instead:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['newvar'] = 'bar';
```

Comment: If you just want a superglobal, use `$_GLOBALS`. Don't bring sessions into this if that's not what you want.